# Pandas - turning a DF column into an Index but without duplication

Tags: python, json, pandas, multi-index

if I have a pandas dataframe like this, and I'd like to turn the 'pol_class' column into the index but only have it so that it doesn't duplicate (pol_class has 3 values: Negative, Neutral, Positive), how would I best go by doing that?

[image]

I'm trying to get it into a format so that I can call pandas' .to_json(orient = 'index') format eventually to get it into this JSON format... (i'll be dropping the 'time_by_min' column and just using the other two non-pol_class columns)

```
[{ 
      "key" : "Negative" , 
      "values" : [ [ 1439489400000, 4] , [ 1439489460000, 8],
       [ 1439489520000, 5], 
       ...]
},
{
       "key" : "Neutral" ,
       "values" : [ [ 1439489400000, 0] , [ 1439489460000, 4],
       [ 1439489520000, 15],  
       ...]
},
{
       "key" : "Positive" ,
       "values" : [ [ 1439489400000, 6] , [ 1439489460000, 14],
       [ 1439489520000, 12],  
       ...]
}]
```

Comment: If you make the unique values of `pol_class` the index, your DataFrame will have only 3 rows.  What do you want to be the contents of those rows?

Comment: @BrenBarn - whatever it has to be to call pd.to_json(orient='index') to get it into this^ kind of JSON form? So would that have to be a list of lists, which each inner list being [JStimestamp, count]?

Comment: If your question is about how to get that JSON, you should probably retitle it and maybe reword it.  It sounds like you don't really care about the DataFrame structure at all, you just want a certain kind of JSON.

Comment: an ends to a mean. i would be content just refiguring that dataframe structure because i think the next step i have in mind is correct. But thought i'd make it clear what my next objective was, in case someone could illuminate a better method to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's reproduce your DataFrame from the list of dicts. (Next time you can help us out by posting `df.to_dict('split'))`:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
    { "key" : "Negative" , 
      "values" : [ [ 1439489400000, 4] , [ 1439489460000, 8],
                   [ 1439489520000, 5], ]},
    { "key" : "Neutral" ,
      "values" : [ [ 1439489400000, 0] , [ 1439489460000, 4],
                   [ 1439489520000, 15], ]},
    { "key" : "Positive" ,
      "values" : [ [ 1439489400000, 6] , [ 1439489460000, 14],
                   [ 1439489520000, 12], ]}]


df = pd.concat({ dct['key']:pd.DataFrame(dct['values']) for dct in data})
df.index = df.index.droplevel(level=1)
df.index.names = ['A']
df.columns=['B', 'C']
df = df.reset_index()
#           A              B   C
# 0  Negative  1439489400000   4
# 1  Negative  1439489460000   8
# 2  Negative  1439489520000   5
# 3   Neutral  1439489400000   0
# 4   Neutral  1439489460000   4
# 5   Neutral  1439489520000  15
# 6  Positive  1439489400000   6
# 7  Positive  1439489460000  14
# 8  Positive  1439489520000  12
```

Now we can re-generate the list of dicts from the DataFrame:

```
newdata = [{'key':key, 'values': grp[['B','C']].values.tolist()} 
           for key, grp in df.groupby('A')]
```

The desired JSON can be obtained by calling `json.dumps`:

```
print(json.dumps(newdata))
```

yields

```
[{"values": [[1439489400000, 4], [1439489460000, 8], [1439489520000, 5]], "key": "Negative"}, {"values": [[1439489400000, 0], [1439489460000, 4], [1439489520000, 15]], "key": "Neutral"}, {"values": [[1439489400000, 6], [1439489460000, 14], [1439489520000, 12]], "key": "Positive"}]
```

---

There is only one orientation which makes `df.to_dict` return a list of dicts:
`df.to_dict(orient='records')`. The keys of each dict are column names. Your
desired list of dicts has dicts whose keys are always `'values'` and
`'keys'`. So if we wanted to use `df.to_dict` we would need to manipulate the
given DataFrame into one with just two columns called `'keys'` and
`'values'`... bah, too much work. It is easier to just express the desired list
of dicts as a list comprehension, as shown above.

Comment: this!!! that one-liner newdata code! and thanks for the df.to_dict heads up too, noted!